# Formtastic Datalist Activeadmin not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, datalist, formtastic

I am using the [activeadmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem with [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) I want to add a **datalist** to a particular text field.

```
#FILE app/admin/model.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  permit_params :title, :article_headline_a_id, :article_headline_b_id

  form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
    f.input :article_headline_a_id, :as => :datalist, :collection => Article.pluck(:title)
    f.input :article_headline_b_id, :as => :datalist, :collection => Article.pluck(:title)
    f.actions
  end 
end
```

Everything seems to work fine until I save and check the console I get `article_a_id = 0` instead of the expected id number.

```
#model.rb
  belongs_to :article1, :foreign_key => 'article_headline_a_id', :class_name => "Article"
  belongs_to :article2, :foreign_key => 'article_headline_b_id', :class_name => "Article"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're not mapping the ID to the title try:

```
    f.input :article_headline_a_id, :as => :datalist, :collection => Article.pluck(:title, :id)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Do you know how to display the title instead of the id

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with datalist/pluck sense I've always used select/map, so I would try to map instead of pluck.  :collection => Article.map {|a| a.title, a.id}

Comment: After looking at formtastic's github page, I'm not sure that they have implemented a way to use datalist the way you want/need to use it(with a key value pair).  Check this out: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/1047  If you don't need to use datalist, I'd use select.